# Numpy array element-by-element comparison optimization

Tags: python, optimization, numpy

Let a be a numpy array of length n.
Does the statement 
*a == max(a)*
calculate the expression *max(a)* n-times or just one?

Comment: You probably want [`numpy.amax`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html) rather than plain Python [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max).

Answer (score 1):

It only evaluates `max` once. You could test this yourself by writing your own function:

```
def mymax(x):
    print("Calling mymax.")
    return max(x)
```

Then try

```
a == mymax(a)
```

Comment: Great! Thanks also for the insight about how to test it!

Answer (score 1):

It computes `max(a)` once, then it compares the (scalar) result against each (scalar) element in a, and creates a bool-array for the result.